# The submenu or my mobile version of a page slidesdown and then slidesup

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a mobile menu for a web page that works perfectly when I test it from my hard drive, but when I upload it to the server, it stops functioning correctly. On my computer, when I click on a menu item, it expands and displays its submenu items. If I click on another menu item, the previous submenu slides up to hide while the new submenu is shown. However, when I upload it to the server, clicking on a menu item expands it but immediately hides it again.

This is the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".botonSubmenu").click(function() {
    var submenu = $(this).find(".submenu");
    var iconoSubmenu = $(this).find(".iconosubmenu");

    if (submenu.is(":hidden")) {
      // Cerrar otros submenús abiertos
      $(".submenu").slideUp();
      $(".botonSubmenu").removeClass("activo");
      $(".iconosubmenu").removeClass("activo").addClass('rotar0');

      // Abrir submenú actual
      submenu.slideDown();
      $(this).addClass("activo");
      iconoSubmenu.addClass("activo").removeClass("rotar0").addClass('rotar45');
    } else {
      // Cerrar submenú actual
      submenu.slideUp();
      $(this).removeClass("activo");
      iconoSubmenu.removeClass("activo").removeClass("rotar45").addClass('rotar0');
    }
  });

  $(".iconoMenuCerrar").click(function() {
    // Cerrar todos los submenús y resetear estado
    $(".submenu").slideUp();
    $(".botonSubmenu").removeClass("activo");
    $(".iconosubmenu").removeClass("activo").text("+");
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_pc {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1%;
  right: -2%;
  display: none;
  list-style: none !important;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #947646;
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
  /*#947646;*/
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.menu_pc::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 106px;
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.iconoMenuDesplegable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -20px;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 99;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
  /*#947646;*/
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.iconoMenuDesplegable img {
  width: 80px;
}

.iconoMenuCerrar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 4px solid #947646;
  z-index: 100;
}

.iconoMenuCerrar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu_pc ul {
  padding: 130px 40px 0 40px;
}

.menu_pc ul li {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0.7em 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu_pc ul li ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.menu_pc ul li ul li {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin-left: 3em;
  /*border-bottom: medium solid #947646;*/
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 1.2em;
  margin-right: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
}

.iconosubmenu {
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  /*margin-top: -1rem;
    margin-left: 5rem;*/
}

.rotar45 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.rotar0 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloquecentrado">
  <!-- Esto de abajo es el menú horizontal para PCs-->
  <div class="iconoMenuDesplegable">
    <img src="images/general/botonmenu.png" alt="MENU">
  </div>

  <div class="menu_pc">
    <ul>
      <div class="iconoMenuCerrar">
        <img src="images/general/botonmenucerrar.png" alt="X">
      </div>

      <li>
        <a href="index.html">
          <div class="solomovil menu-icon"><i class="fa-light fa-house"></i></div>Inicio</a>
      </li>

      <li class="botonSubmenu">
        <a>
          <div class="solomovil menu-icon"><i class="fa-light fa-spa"></i></div>Sobre el coaching <span class="solomovil iconosubmenu rotar0">+</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="coaching-quees.html">Qué es el coaching</a></li>
          <li><a href="coaching-beneficios.html">Beneficios del coaching</a></li>
          <li><a href="coaching-metodologia.html">Metodología de coaching</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="botonSubmenu">
        <a>
          <div class="solomovil menu-icon"><i class="fa-light fa-comments"></i></div>Servicios de coaching <span class="solomovil iconosubmenu rotar0">+</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="coaching-individual.html">Coaching individual</a></li>
          <li><a href="coaching-grupos.html">Coaching grupo</a></li>
          <li><a href="coaching-parejas.html">Coaching de parejas</a></li>
          <li><a href="coaching-talleres.html">Talleres de autoconocimiento</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="botonSubmenu">
        <a>
          <div class="solomovil menu-icon"><i class="fa-light fa-users"></i></div>Testimonios <span class="solomovil iconosubmenu rotar0">+</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="testimonios.html">Testimonios</a></li>
          <li><a href="casosdeexito.html">Casos de éxito</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="botonSubmenu">
        <a>
          <div class="solomovil menu-icon"><i class="fa-light fa-square-info"></i></div>Más información <span class="solomovil iconosubmenu rotar0">+</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="tarifas.html">Tarifas y paquetes</a></li>
          <li><a href="preguntasfrecuentes.html">Preguntas Frecuentes</a></li>
          <li><a href="recursos.html">Recursos adicionales</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="contacto.html">
          <div class="solomovil menu-icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i></div>Contacto</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="blog.html">
          <div class="solomovil menu-icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-blog"></i></div>Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have been trying different scripts with the help of ChatGPT, but none of them are functioning properly. Since the only way I can test the operation on mobile devices is by opening the page on my phone, I don't know how to debug this problem.

Comment: PS, you can easily switch Desktop/Mobile in i.e: Chrome or Firefox's Dev tools